# Finding a polynomial having the curve solution

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, geometry, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I'm studying complex algebraic curves and I've been asked to show that a certain subset of $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ is a complex algebraic curve. Now, I imagine that I have to find the polynomial P(x,y) such that the solution to P(x,y)=0 is the given subset.

As I'm having trouble figuring out how to actually solve this with complex numbers and arbitrary polynomials, I've decided to reduce the problem to the simplest case and the real numbers.

So, if I have a polynomial P(x,y)=ax+by, finding the curve solution is trivial, as it is in fact (t, -at/b) and trivially a line since the factors are lineal. But the inverse problem, having a line (t, at+b) and having to find the polynomial P(x,y)=ax+by that has the given line as a solution of P(x,y)=0...

I found out that I don't know how to do that, not even in this simple case. So, I wonder how to do this and if knowing how to do it in the simple case would help me in the complex case above.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem can be stated as follows:

> If a curve has a polynomial parametrization, find an implicit polynomial equation for it.

The key word here is *elimination*: write $x=f(t), y=g(t)$ and eliminate $t$ to find $P(x,y)=0$.

The key tool for elimination is the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).

The resultant can be computed by hand but it is a large determinant and is best found with a computer, for instance with [Resultant](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resultant.html) in Mathematica and WolframAlpha.

In your example, you can do [Resultant[x-t,y+a t /b,t]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5Bx-t,y%2Ba+t+%2Fb,t%5D) and find $-(a x + b y)/b$.

Here is a more interesting example:
Take the curve $x=t^2-t,y=t^3$. Then 
[Resultant[x-t^2+t,y-t^3,t]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5Bx-t%5E2%2Bt,y-t%5E3,t%5D) gives $x^3 + 3 x y - y^2 + y$.

In general, you use `Resultant[x-f(t),y-g(t),t]`.

Comment: I am not sure this solves my question. For example, if I have a set of points (t, 3t+5) that define a curve, what would it be the polynomial P(x,y) that has that set of points as a solution for P(x,y)=0?

Comment: `Resultant[x-t,y-(3t+5),t]` gives $3 x - y + 5$. See [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5Bx-t,y-(3t%2B5),t%5D).

Comment: Oh, it seems to work! Thank you! The problem I have now is that I don't know how to interpret this from an algebraic geometry point of view, since I don't think I can use this to prove that a certain set is a complex algebraic curve, but I'll figure something out, thank you again!